# Subset data.table fulfilling condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that I want so subset with only those columns, that have a length larger than length_x.

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) > length_x)]
```

and also

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) > length_x), with = FALSE]
```

will only return a logical vector assigning to each column a TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

The output is a `list` of logical vector with each element length 1.  We can `unlist` it to create a logical `vector` and use that to subset the columns

```
i1 <- DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) > length_x))]
DT[, i1, with = FALSE]
```

---

Or creating a logical index with `colSums`

```
DT[, DT[, colSums(!is.na(.SD)) > length_x], with = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DT <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10 * 5, 
      replace = TRUE), nrow = 10))
length_x <- 6
```